# Js reduce method ,why 0 at end?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, reduce

Complete the square sum function so that it squares each number passed into it and then sums the results together. For example, for `[1, 2, 2]` it should return `9` because `1^2 + 2^2 + 2^2 = 9`.

I managed to do the task but I did not understand why i had to add 0 at the end to pass the test. If i remove that 0,it doesn't pass. Can anyone please explain it ? I am newbie.

```
function numbers (numbers) {

return numbers.map((num) => num ** 2).reduce((initValue, currentValue) => initValue + currentValue,0)

}
```

Comment: It's the initial `initValue`. Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#syntax) is always useful.

Comment: should work identically (in this case) without it though

Comment: @JaromandaX except if the array is empty.

Comment: sure, as I did say *in this case* where an array is being passed